# Creating your own NSNotificationCenter methods

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Please, explain me, how can I create my own NSNotificationCenter method instead of

```
- (id)addObserverForName:(NSString *)name object:(id)obj queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification *))block
```

Comment: you can use categories or inheritance but why do you need it?

Comment: It's part of my education program, i need to create my own method to understand all the features of this method
Can you explain how to use categories to solve this task?

Comment: I mean, what exactly code should I write?
I can't understand how to get access to default notification center...